# How to hide / show rows across multiple worksheets based on a cell value on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to come up with a more efficient, faster running way to adapt this formula so that it hides / shows the same rows across multiple worksheets based on the value of D10 on the 'Input' tab, where this macro is stored.

I have tried everything I can find but it is looking like I will have to list out the exact same row references with the new worksheets name directly below the 1st worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Prevents general pop-ups
Application.Calculation = xlManual 'Formulas are not calculated
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'What the user see's on screen will not change

If Intersect(Target, Range("D10")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Hides all major city information so just the titles are shown.
If Target.Address = ("$D$10") And Target.Value = "" Then
Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Unprotect
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("54:63").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("68:77").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("82:91").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("96:105").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("18:31").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("23:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True

'Unhides 'London' under the major cities section and keeps the rest hidden.
ElseIf Target.Address = ("$D$10") And Target = "UK" Then
Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Unprotect
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("68").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("82").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("96").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("55:63").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("69:77").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("83:91").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("97:105").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("24:28").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("18:23").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True

'Unhides 'French Riviera' & 'Paris' under the major cities section and keeps the rest hidden.
ElseIf Target.Address = ("$D$10") And Target = "France" Then
Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Unprotect
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("55:56").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("69:70").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("83:84").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("97:98").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("68").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("82").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("96").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("57:63").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("71:77").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("85:91").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("99:105").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("30:34").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("18:29").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("35:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True

'Unhides 'Barcelona' & 'Madrid' under the major cities section and keeps the rest hidden.
ElseIf Target.Address = ("$D$10") And Target = "Spain" Then
Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Unprotect
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("57:58").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("71:72").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("85:86").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("99:100").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("54:56").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("59:63").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("68:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("73:77").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("82:84").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("87:91").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("96:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("101:105").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("36:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("18:35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("41:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True

'Unhides 'Florence', 'Maples', 'Milan', 'Rome' & 'Venice' under the major cities section and keeps the rest hidden.
ElseIf Target.Address = ("$D$10") And Target = "Italy" Then
Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Unprotect
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("59:63").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("73:77").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("87:91").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("101:105").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("54:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("68:72").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("82:86").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("96:100").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("42:46").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("18:41").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("47").EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If

Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Rows("108:121").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Sheets("Weekly Report - New").Protect

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This works fine (if a bit slow) for the "Weekly Report - New" worksheet. I now need it to do the same for the "Cumulative Report - New" worksheet.

Comment: I would create `Union`s of the rows that will be hidden together and then just hide the `Union`'s - this will be good for readability. Also, instead of checking the address, check the `Intersect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all reduce your hide and unhide actions to one for `true` and one for `false` to speed it up. For Example

```
ws.Range("54:54,68:68,82:82,96:96,24:28").EntireRow.Hidden = False
ws.Range("55:63,69:77,83:91,97:105,18:23,29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Note you must use `Range` instead of `Rows` here.

And put your code into a procedure so you can re-use it for any sheet. Note that you need to adjust the code for `France`, `Spain` and `Italy`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Prevents general pop-ups
    Application.Calculation = xlManual 'Formulas are not calculated
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'What the user see's on screen will not change

    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D10")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' call the function
    HideAndUnhideRows ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weekly Report - New"), Me.Range("D10").Value
    HideAndUnhideRows ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cumulative Report - New"), Me.Range("D10").Value

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub HideAndUnhideRows(ws As Worksheet, Criteria As String)
    ws.Unprotect
    Select Case Criteria

    Case "" 'Hides all major city information so just the titles are shown.
        ws.Range("54:63,68:77,82:91,96:105,23:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ws.Range("18:31").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Case "UK" 'Unhides 'London' under the major cities section and keeps the rest hidden.
        ws.Range("54:54,68:68,82:82,96:96,24:28").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ws.Range("55:63,69:77,83:91,97:105,18:23,29:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Case "France" 'Unhides 'French Riviera' & 'Paris' under the major cities section and keeps the rest hidden.

    Case "Spain" 'Unhides 'Barcelona' & 'Madrid' under the major cities section and keeps the rest hidden.

    Case "Italy" 'Unhides 'Florence', 'Maples', 'Milan', 'Rome' & 'Venice' under the major cities section and keeps the rest hidden.

    End Select

    ws.Range("108:121").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ws.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do we need to use `Range`instead `Rows` ? I might learn something from this too.

Comment: Damn you guys work quick, I am just adjusting a different part of it and then I will give this a go, thank you all for the speedy response!

Comment: @Damian Because `Rows` does not accept non-continuous comma separated address like `54:63,68:77`, but `Range` does. And if addresses are hardcoded anyway I avoid using `union` to make it even shorter and faster.

Comment: Shorter I get it, but how does it  get faster than `Union()` don't they do the same afterall @Pᴇʜ?

Comment: Ok just finished getting it all working, had to tweak it because of some other elements of the file but its essentially exactly as written.

Thank you very much (: (all working perfectly)

Comment: @Damian Actually I didn't test it, it was more of a theoretical nature. But every function call takes its time and you call `Rows` several times and `union` while I call only `Range` once. So I bet one function call only must be faster since they do almost the same thing (and hopfully both do it efficiently). Nevertheless the address that `Range` can take has a length limit so you will probably never notice the difference of a piece of a second between both. • The main reason was to have a better human readable code which is worth a lot more than the last tiny bit of speed.

Comment: I can't see where to mark it as solved? Also apparently I can't upvote thing because i dont have enough rep or something. Need 15 or more and I'm guessing I have 0 because new account, I upvoted it anyway.

Comment: @Josh it is explained in the link (I gave in my comment) how to mark it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are a ton of different rows to hide and unhide I did the first example which you can use to do the rest:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, SheetNames
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Prevents general pop-ups
Application.Calculation = xlManual 'Formulas are not calculated
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'What the user see's on screen will not change

If Intersect(Target, Range("D10")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
SheetNames = Array("Weekly Report - New", "Cumulative Report - New")


StrValue = Target.Value
Select Case StrValue
    'Hides all major city information so just the titles are shown.
    Case vbNullString
        For i = 0 To 1
            Set ws = wb.Sheets(SheetNames(i))
            With ws
                .Unprotect
                Union(.Rows("54:63"), .Rows("68:77"), .Rows("82:91"), .Rows("96:105"), .Rows("23:47")). _
                    EntireRow.Hidden = True
                .Rows("18:31").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End With
        Next i

    'All the other cases

End Select
```

What I did there was a loop for each worksheet you need to work in (assuming both have the same data) and using what urdearboy said about the union for more readability and faster process.

Hope this points you in the right direction. IF you need anymore help just ask.